# Is functional integration useful in theoretical economics?

Tags: functional-analysis, economics

[Definition of functional integration here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration)

> Functional integration is a collection of results in mathematics and
>   physics where the domain of an integral is no longer a region of
>   space, but a space of functions. Functional integrals arise in
>   probability, in the study of partial differential equations and in
>   Feynman's approach to the quantum mechanics of particles and fields

Comment: It is a useful approach when solving exotic variations of the Black-Scholes equation for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the work of [Mike Tehranchi](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~mike/) and collaborators, who have worked on the theory of infinite-dimensional stochastic differential equations.

For example, when analysing [interest rate derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_rate_derivatives) the state of the system is not described by a point (as it would be when analysing derivatives of stocks) but by a function, and the evolution of this state over time naturally leads to functional analytic techniques.

Typically the function in question models the [yield curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve) but there are many other curves that are objects of study in finance.